# Attribute-Class, System.Attribute, Complex-Type

Tags: c#

It is possible do declare a AttributeClass with a filed and constructor of complex type?

**The answer is: No! see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38509077/2935383**

Scroll down for a other solution.

My try:

Own attribute-class

```
class Attr : System.Attribute {
    private string _author;
    private A[] _additionalParam;

    public string Author{ get { return _author; } }
    public A[] Add{ get { return _additionalParam; } }

    public Attr( string author, params A[] add ){
        _author = author;
        _additionalParam = add;
    }
}
```

Complex type

```
class A{
    public string abc;
    public string def;

    public A( string a, string b ){
        abc = a;
        def = b;
    }
}
```

Usage attribute class

```
//this dosn't work
[Attr("me ;)", new A("a","b"), new A("c", "d")] 
TestClass{

}
```

Cannot use `new A("a","b")`, it is not constant.

**Edit**:
constructor also take the complex type ;)

---

### **My solution:**

I've defined a second Attribute-Class and set it to multiple.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
class AdditionlAttr : System.Attribute
    public string abc;
    public string def;

    public AdditionlAttr( string a, string b ){
        abc = a;
        def = b;
    }
}
```

And change the `Attr`-Class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
class Attr : System.Attribute {
    private string _author;

    public string Author{ get { return _author; } }

    public Attr( string author ){
        _author = author;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[Attr("me ;)"]
[AdditionlAttr("a","b")]
[AdditionlAttr("c","d")]
TestClass{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this. From section 17.1.3 of the [C# Language Specification 5.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029):

> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class are limited to the *attribute parameter types* which are:
>
> - One of the following types: `bool`, `byte`, `char`, `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, `sbyte`, `short`, `string`, `uint`, `ulong`, `ushort`
> - The type `object`
> - The type `System.Type`
> - An enum type [...]
> - Single-dimensional arrays of the above
>
> A constructor argument or public field which does not have one of these types, cannot be used as a positional or named parameter in an attribute specification.

Comment: thank you. have you an link to this document? And why vote down. I cannot find this information on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @raiserle: I've added a link into the answer.

Comment: thank you again. (link dosn't work) ;)
I've searched this chapter 17.1.3 on google: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/aa664615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @raiserle: The link works for me - what happens for you? I would strongly advise you *not* to use the hyperlinked version of the C# specification on MSDN, as it's massively out of date. (The version you linked to doesn't cover generics, which were introduced in C# 2 in 2005...)

Comment: @raiserle: Um, there are only two versions of this answer: one without a link, and one with a link. I didn't *change* the link at any time.